# Rspec: Call a method after a failure

Tags: rspec

I'm trying to find out how to call a method in a spec helper after each failure. I feel bad asking this question because it seems like it'd have been asked before, but it's sort of unGoogleable to me since all I find is detecting failures in after(:each).

Basically, I want to set up a notification to myself, something like:

```
def you_failed
    system "say -v Bad test failed"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create a custom formatter. Look at the Core::BaseFormatter and Core::BaseTextFormatter. You'll find a example_failed method. Override this method in your custom formatter to include the code to call when the example fails. Note this can run multiple times depending on the number of failed tests.